Pickles with protons
I'm not really sure this should be a physics problem, but maybe it has some connection.
People make pickles with acid, typically lactic acid or vinegar. It is suggested that the acid environment, or $\mathrm{H^+}$ ions is vital. What if we shine a beam of protons onto the vegetables to provide  $\mathrm{H^+}$? Will we obtain pickles?

When pickling, you should use a sealed container to keep out bacteria and moulds. But that's just a minor engineering problem.

Don't use a high energy proton beam. Otherwise, you risk damaging the vegetables. Just ask Anatoli Bugorski...

A chemist says $H^+$ ions don't exist... 1.6 C/fm$^3$ is too high a charge density: https://www.youtube.com/shorts/TrEoXKjBIyc

@JEB 'Bare protons" exist in a particle beam, but while they're absorbed they bind to other molecules. "$\mathrm{H^+}$" in solution is bound to at least one water molecule. https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/41997/does-the-hydrogen-ion-actually-exist https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/32558/why-are-hydrogen-ions-always-associated-with-another-molecule

You would not acidify food by firing a beam of protons at it. You would simply cook it as the kinetic energy of the protons was converted to heat.
Everyday objects are approximately electrically neutral i.e. they have equal numbers of positive and negative charges. The low pH of pickled food does not come from adding proton to it. It is due to the acids (acetic acid and lactic acid) dissociating into protons and the anion of the acid e.g. for acetic acid:
$$ \textrm{CH}_3\textrm{COOH} \to \textrm{H}^+ + \textrm{CH}_3\textrm{COO}^-$$
If you add protons to the food by firing a proton beam at it you will be positively charging the food and that positive charge will be quickly neutralised by negative charges from the environment. The end result will be some complex mixture of chemicals as a proton beam energy is typically many orders of magnitude greater than chemical bond energies so the beam will break chemical bonds at random. It would probably taste horrible!
For completeness we should note that the flavour of pickled food comes from the anion rather than the $\mathrm{H}^+$. I have personally tasted sulphuric and hydrochloric acids (don't judge me - we experimental scientists do this sort of thing) and they just taste sour and not even remotely like the flavours you get from pickling food.

Cool. So if we positively charge the whole pickling environment, the vegetables will taste really sour?

Saying that proton beams are energetic, I wonder whether there will be a columb explosion…

Surely a beam of antiprotons would fix this problem. ;)

@MaYe Your sour taste receptors are essentially just proton receptors. Any excess positively charged protons cause a sour flavor.

@DavidS I'm going to ask "What do antiprotons taste like?" but I'm going to wait until early next April to post it - start watching for it on the 1st :-)

It should also be noted that free protons are rare in acids. It's usually bound in a molecular ion of the form $\textrm{H}^+(\textrm{H}_2\textrm{O})_n$. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydronium
